# Is Apache Webserver required to be installed on a GCP VM to monitor it via Stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-compute-engine

I am looking at the documentation from google to monitor a GCE VM instance using Stackdriver , the documentation seems to suggest that I install Apache webserver to enable Stackdriver to monitor the GCE instance.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp

Is that a hard requirement to install Apache Webserver on the instance to enable Stackdriver monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a hard requirement. The following steps are the simplest ones:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#linux-install